# Simple Timeout method that accepts a Func<T> is not awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to create a simple reusable timeout method, that is totally asynchronous. For some reason, my Timeout method is not being awaited, and I am stumped as to why.

```
    [Fact]
    public async void TestTimeOut()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var Thrown = false;
        try
        {
            await TimeOut(() => Task.Delay(5000), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            //** Never Hit
            Thrown = true;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Assert.True(sw.Elapsed >= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)); //** fails nothing is awaited, executes in less than 40ms

        Assert.True(Thrown); //** Fails
    }

    private async Task<T> TimeOut<T>(Func<T> method, TimeSpan timeOut)
    {
        using (var ctsForTask = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var taskTimeOut = Task.Delay(timeOut);
            Task<T> task = Task.Run(() => method(), ctsForTask.Token);
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, taskTimeOut))
            {
                ctsForTask.Cancel();
                throw new OperationCanceledException(ctsForTask.Token);
            }
            return task.Result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Timeout` is being awaited, but the `() => Task.Delay(5000)` lambda is not. Since `Task.Run` doesn't know that `T` is a `Task`, it returns immediately. Use `Func<Task<T>>` or `Func<Task>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Func<Task<T>> method` parameter and await the result in the timout method